# How to think when solving boolean expressions?

Tags: java, boolean-expression

I have the following question:

**Let a and b be boolean variables. Is it possible to set values for a and b to have the following expression evaluate as false? b or (((not a) or (not a)) or (a or (not b)))**

What would be the best way to go about this? I know that working out all four possibilities on a piece of paper would give me the answer but is there in an effective strategy to deal with this kind of problem?

Comment: do a truth table

Comment: There is a duplication int the evaluation: (not a) OR (not a) is ALWAYS (not a)

Comment: De Morgan laws are also useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Comment: Why the java tag? If you want to end up with a program, then why aren't you showing your efforts here?!

Comment: @GhostCat I don't want to end up with a java program. I just started out and this was a build up exercise

Comment: What's your end goal? Do you want to find result for this particular expression or any expression? Do you need in code or just the logic to solve it?

Comment: Note that the only binary operator is OR, which means you can discard the parentheses.

Comment: @amit77309 I was just looking for how to think about problems like these, since I just started out with Java. I'm not actually using this in code

Comment: Then dont use tags that dont relate to your question ;-)

Comment: Is this not part of Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get the answer by deduction.

```
b or (((not a) or (not a)) or (a or (not b)))
```

As we can see here, `b` must be false for the whole expression to be false, because it is an operand of the OR operator:

```
b or ...
```

However, on the right side, if `b` is false, then `not b` would be true, making this:

```
(a or (not b))
```

true.

Now our expression has become:

```
false or (((not a) or (not a)) or true)
```

As you can see pretty clearly here, the right side must evaluate to true ad the whole thing evaluates to true. Therefore, the answer is *no*.

Comment: Nice explanation. And (not a) OR (not a) can also be simplified to (not a)
So you have `false or ((not a) or true)`

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small program or unit test.

```
  @Test
  public void testSomeThing() {
    System.out.println(check(true, true));
    System.out.println(check(true, false));
    System.out.println(check(false, true));
    System.out.println(check(false, false));

  }

  private boolean check(final boolean a, final boolean b) {
    return b || (((!a) || (!a)) || (a || (!b)));
  }
```

I preserved the brackets even though some of them could be removed.

The result is:
true
true
true
true

So the answer to your question :

> Is it possible to set values for a and b to have the following expression evaluate as false?

is "No you can't".

Answer (score 1):

An answer to the second part: in the real world you would be using a so call [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) (for satisfiability). Meaning: you can simplify small equations manually, but in the real world, you might have equations with millions of variables - and then you turn to SAT solvers.

Diving in how such tools work is an excellent entry point to fundamental topics of computer science. See resp. listen to this [podcast](http://www.se-radio.net/2017/07/se-radio-episode-298-moshe-vardi-on-p-versus-np/) for example. It discusses the differences between P and NP - and then spents a lot of time explaining why we are able to solve *large* SAT problems (which are in NP) efficiently nowadays.